# not redirecting after logged in

Tags: php, authentication

I have made a login function, but it will not redirect to the right page when I'm loggedin. Does somebody have a clue to fix this problem?

Here is a part of the code for my loginform.

```
session_start();
if(isset ($_SESSION['loggedin']))
{
     header( "Location: account.phtml" ) ;
}

if (isset($_POST["submit"]))
{
     $username = $_POST ["username"];
     $password = $_POST ["password"];

     if ($username && $password)
     {
         $query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM user WHERE username='$username'");

         if($query)
         {
             $numrows = mysql_num_rows($query);
             if($numrows != 0)
             {
                 while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query))
                 {
                     $dbusername = $row ['username'];
                     $dbpassword = $row ['password'];
                 }
                 if ($username == $dbusername && $password == $dbpassword)
                 {
                     $_SESSION['username'] = $dbusername;
                     $_SESSION['loggedin'] = true;
                     header("Location: account.phtml");
                 }
             }
         }
         else{}
     }
}
```

Here is a part from my loginform.

```
    <form class="form-horizontal" role="form" method="post" target="account.phtml">
         <!-- here comes my loginform -->
    </form>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The most likely cause is that your headers have already been sent by the time you issue the redirect. If this is the case then PHP will be emitting a warning message - why can't you see it? Hence the first step would be to explicit trigger a warning before the session_start() and make sure that your error reporting is working correctly.

If that was the only issue then your question would be closed as a duplicate of the many, many other questions which ultimately realte to the same root cause.

The next problem is that you don't stop the code executing after the head('Location:...) function (hint: if you put a print statement in between the header() and exit you may be able to get some diagnostic information about what the code is doing).

The next issue is that your code is wide open to SQL injection. Consider what would happen if

```
$_POST ["username"]="nouser' UNION SELECT 'admin' AS username, '' AS password "
                   ."WHERE 'a'='a";
```

The next issue is here:

```
if(isset ($_SESSION['loggedin']))
```

What if $_SESSION['loggedin']==false?

Comment: Thanks a lot, you really did help me a lot with your answer!

Answer (score 1):

change this..

```
header("Location: account.phtml");
```

to

```
header("Location: {you want to navigate page}")
```

with url you want to navigate.
i think you redirect on working page.your form target and navigate url are same.

Comment: like @ajay-patel says:
 <form ...target="account.phtml">
and
header("Location: account.phtml");
Are the same ...
Change header("Location: into the page you want to visit after login.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
if (isset($_SESSION['user_id']) && $_SESSION['user_id']) {
    header('Location: user.php?id=' . $_SESSION['user_id']); 
   exit;
}
```